# How can I capture the standard output of clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have some printlns I need to capture from a Clojure program and I was wondering how I could capture the output?

I have tried:

```
(binding [a *out*]
    (println "h")
    a
)
```

: but this doesn't work

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
(with-out-str (println "this should return as a string"))
```

Answer (score 8):

Just to expand a little on Michiel's answer, when you want to capture output to a file you can combine `with-out-str` with `spit`.

When you don't want to build up a huge string in memory before writing it out then you can use `with-out-writer` from the `clojure.contrib.io` library.

`with-out-writer` is a macro that nicely encapsulates the correct opening and closing of the file resource and the binding of a writer on that file to `*out*` while executing the code in its body.

Answer (score 3):

Michiel's exactly right. Since I can't add code in a comment on his answer, here's what `with-out-str` does under the covers, so you can compare it with your attempt:

```
user=> (macroexpand-1 '(with-out-str (println "output")))
(clojure.core/let [s__4091__auto__ (new java.io.StringWriter)]
  (clojure.core/binding [clojure.core/*out* s__4091__auto__]
    (println "output")
    (clojure.core/str s__4091__auto__)))
```

Your code was binding the existing standard output stream to a variable, printing to that stream, and then asking the stream for its value via the variable; however, the value of the stream was of course not the bytes that had been printed to it. So `with-out-str` binds a newly created `StringWriter` to `*out*` temporarily, and finally queries the string value of that temporary writer.